# Get the connection string not from App.Config?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The code generation of adding `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` adds the following class and App.config file.

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=MyDbContext")
    {
    }
```

**App.Config**

```xml
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbContext" 
     connectionString="data source=...;initial catalog=...;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

However, I already have the connection string saved in `Properties.Settings.Default.MyDbConnString`. How to change the code to use the one in the properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the constructor argument name for [`DbContext(String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.) constructor

```
public DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString);
```

> Constructs a new context instance using the given string as the name or connection string for the database to which a connection will be made

You can use the full connection string in the constructor so update context to use the value stored in properties.

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public MyDbContext()
        : base(Properties.Settings.Default.MyDbConnString) {
    }
}
```

And remove the on in the config file to avoid any conflicts.

Comment: the connection string in the config does not have to removed, there won't be any conflicts. You could even create one context targeting a DB with a local connection string and one targeting a db with a connection string in the app.config. Default connection strings in the app.config are also quite useful if you want to use pregenerated views.